# Abrir arquivo word pelo delphi

Tags: delphi

Tenho um sistema que faz integração com o **MS-Word** eu consigo fazer quase tudo nele, só não conseguir abrir o documento e deixar ele como *somente de leitura* para que o usuário não possa fazer modificações. atualmente meu código esta assim:

```
//Cria objeto principal de controle
try
  with OleContainer do
  begin
    if OleObjectInterface <> Nil then
    begin
      DestroyObject;
    end;
    //Nome do arquivo usado para abrir o arquivo de entrevista
    vNomeArquivo  := DM.tbParamPASTA_BD.AsString+'\MODELOS\'+DM2.qryConsultasMODELO.AsString;   
    try
      OleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile(vNomeArquivo, OF_READ);
      OleContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);
      Perform(WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, MK_LBUTTON, 0);
    except
      //Fechar o arquivo
      DestroyObject;
    end;
  end;
finally
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  OleContainer.TabStop := False;
```

end;

> PS: Eu não quero abrir um documento que tenha o atributo *ReadOnly* eu
>   quero impedir que o usuário não altere o documento tipo modo Protegido
>   Irrestrito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não usamos muito o `olecontainer`, mas para as nossas necessidades aqui quando precisamos deixar o documento `readonly` para o usuário nos usamos a seguinte linha..:

```
OleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile(vNomeArquivo, false);
OleContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);
OleContainer.OleObject.Protect(3);
Perform(WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, MK_LBUTTON, 0);
```

Comment: Vou ver se funciona...

Comment: Cara ficou show!!!